# Why does the new about page show a different score for an answer of the question used as example?

Tags: support, tour

On [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/about), I noticed that one of the answers for the question used as example is first shown with a score of 4, and then with a score of 9.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

The score of that answer is actually 31, as visible in [What's the reason for calling cheap seats at the theatre nosebleed seats?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/whats-the-reason-for-calling-cheap-seats-at-the-theatre-nosebleed-seats) and [the answer didn't get any recent votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/33860/timeline).

> [image: screenshot]

Also, from the first screenshot, it seems I up-voted the answer, which is not what I did. I guess it is shown accepted, and up-voted to show how an up-voted, or accepted answer appears.

Why isn't the answer score the current one? Why do the screenshots shown in the about page show different scores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of it as showing a real question or that you are somehow voting on it. It's just an example.

The answer scores aren't real because we want to do specific things with them. So, in the first example, we start with two evenly voted answers, then one "gets" an upvote and moves to the top of the list, and then gets accepted.

Keep in mind that this page is aimed at new users and is shown the exact same way to everyone regardless of whether or not they're already logged in. It is in no way linked to your account or your actions on the site and we may occasionally [reject reality and substitute our own](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8qcccZy03s).

Comment: I got it: Only the posts' text is used, to avoid inventing a question's example. I didn't get what the animation was doing; I thought it was scrolling to show another answer. `:)`